# Maven - can i include third-party dependencies during app's runtime?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, dependencies

Maven - can i include third-party dependency during app runtime (mb using command line)?

Comment: Do you want a provided scope? This would cause the dependencies to not be included in your artifact.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst, it's rather runtime scope than provided. Do you know how to include dependency from cli to the project like `mvn myproject.jar mydependencyId`?

Comment: Yes... there are a couple of was to do this, but they have nothing to do with maven. I'll post an answer but you'll need to edit your question.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking of a completely different approach.  But now I see what you are asking.  I don't normally use maven to execute my applications. But I think you can use "mvn exec:java" and a local pom to do this.  I'll answer this question later if no one else gets to it before I get a chance to look into it...

Comment: Please elaborate what app runtime you're referring to. How are you packaging and then executing your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dependency is not required for compilation, but is required for execution or test execution you can use "runtime" [dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). For example:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```